# terraform - for loop for replica - region name for global table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am creating aws global table with terraform with multi-region replication.

```
    resource "aws_dynamodb_global_table" "test_table" {
  depends_on = ["aws_dynamodb_table.us-east-1", "aws_dynamodb_table.us-west-2"]
  provider   = "aws.us-east-1"

  name = "test"

  replica {
    region_name = "us-east-1"
  }

  replica {
    region_name = "us-west-2"
  }
}
```

Next I am creating both the regional tables as modules with `count` `interpolation` and returning ARN for each table.

How do I create Global Table as module where I add reference to both tables? `depends_on` and `replica` in this case.

Updated with tried approach:

```
//Templ1 
{ region_name = "${region_name}" }

//Templ2
  ${value} 

data "template_file" "replica_region" {
  template = "${file("${path.module}/replica-region.json.tmpl")}" 
  count = "${length(var.regions)}"
  vars {
    region_name = "${element(var.regions, count.index)}"
  }
}

data "template_file" "replica_regional" {
  template = "${file("${path.module}/replica-regional.json.tmpl")}" 
  vars {
    value = "${join(",", data.template_file.replica_region.*.rendered)}"
  }
}
```

I am passing below to global table

```
replica = [ "${data.template_file.replica_regional.rendered}" ]
```

but getting error `replica.0.region_name : required field is not set` where as when I do output for `"${data.template_file.replica_regional.rendered}"` I get below output.

```
 { region_name = "us-east-1" },{ region_name = "us-west-2" }
```

And If I hardcode above terraform recipe works just fine. What Am i missing? I am referring to this article [Link](http://medium.com/ovni/terraform-templating-and-loops-9a88c0786c5c)

Answer (score 1):

I ended up setting it as a variable as below in `variables.tf` and using it directly in global db resource.

```
    replica = [
        {
            region_name = "us-east-1"
        },
        {
            region_name = "us-west-1"
        }
    ]
```